# Making (POST) signed requests to AWS IAM using C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, http-post, amazon-iam

I am trying follow the example given at AWS documentation [Signing AWS requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html) and make a ListUsers call in C#. I have arrived till the last stage of generating the signature (i.e ready to submit the signed request given at [signature-4 request examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html)). But the code I pasted below is throwing 'bad request' exception when submitted.

```
 static void submitSignedRequest(string my_access_key, string my_secret_key, string signature, string curr_utc_date_string, string curr_utc_datetime_string)
    {
        string url = "https://iam.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListUsers&Version=2010-05-08&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&" +
                        "X-Amz-Credential=" + my_access_key + "/" + curr_utc_date_string + "/us-east-1/iam/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=" + curr_utc_datetime_string +
                            "&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date&X-Amz-Signature=" + signature;
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Host = "iam.amazonaws.com";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
        WebHeaderCollection headers = (request as HttpWebRequest).Headers;


        headers.Add("Authorization", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=" + my_access_key +"/" + curr_utc_date_string + "/us-east-1/iam/aws4_request, " +
            "SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=" + signature);
        headers.Add("x-amz-date", curr_utc_datetime_string);

        HttpWebResponse response;
        try
        {
            response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Error Message:    " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Output i get is:

```
Error Message:    The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Can some one help me what wrong I am doing here?

Edit:

I solved this finally by myself. I had to transform it to below. (answer is for RDS though I believe it's visible what the differences are).

```
string url = "https://rds.us-west-1.amazonaws.com";
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

        //  ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = "Action=DescribeDBInstances&Version=2013-09-09";
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Host = "rds.us-west-1.amazonaws.com";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
        //  request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        WebHeaderCollection headers = (request as HttpWebRequest).Headers;

        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=" + my_access_key + "/" + curr_utc_date_string + "/us-west-1/rds/aws4_request, " +
            "SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=" + signature);
        request.Headers.Add("x-amz-date", curr_utc_datetime_string);
```

Comment: Try to get and display the body of the `400 Bad Request` response (sorry, not a C# person so I can't tell you specifically how).  The 400 response [has multiple possible meanings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html), 2 of which are related to the signature itself, and the others indicate other problems.  There should be a body on that response, that gives more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have solved it finally by myself. (edited my post and provided the answer)

Answer (score 3):

> Can some one help me what wrong I am doing here?

Maybe, but I strongly suggest to skip this endeavor all together and just use the excellent [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) for all your AWS API interactions instead, because it indeed *helps take the complexity out of coding by providing .NET APIs for many AWS services including Amazon S3, Amazon EC2, DynamoDB and more*.

- I'm working with AWS for years in various environments and with all sorts of languages, and I have never even bothered to look into using their API without the assistance of one of the [multitude of SDKs](http://aws.amazon.com/tools/) they are offering, most of which offer high level tooling in addition to making working with the API from your respective language much easier in the first place.

But if you really need or want to do it yourself, I suggest to simply take a look at the source code of these very SDKs, which are all [available at GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net), including the one for the [AWS SDK for .NET](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net) - regarding the issue at hand, you might want to start looking into [AWS4Signer.cs](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/10fef6f83449b416044573b0cf39ea3c6621edd7/AWSSDK_DotNet35/Amazon.Runtime/Internal/Auth/AWS4Signer.cs) for example.

- Please note that AWS has just released the significantly overhauled version 2, see [GA Release of AWS SDK for .NET Version 2](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx3OU5NBCTSBJ7D/GA-Release-of-AWS-SDK-for-NET-Version-2) for details.

Comment: I was actually writing this for windows phone 7 when I got stuck above, which didn't have any SDK till now. But the GA release link seems encouraging as it says 'support for windows phone 8', let me see if this makes my life easier. 

Nevertheless, thanks for the quick reply and pointers.  I am still keeping this question open to see if the above can be fixed somehow

Comment: I tried with looking at the SDK but it was little too much for me to tweak and/or adopt it. Got my problem solved myself though.

Thanks for the help nevertheless.

Comment: I could use .NET SDK for S3 and some other aws service, how about API Gateway? How can I send request to IAM protected endpoint on API Gateway? I need to sign the request with aws keys before calling the api.